# How do I solve $y'=\frac{y}{x}\frac{x-y}{x+y}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a solution for

$y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

Now I have this new problem:

$y'=\frac{y}{x}\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

My first approach was to solve it by parts; that way I could have re-used my solution for $\frac{x-y}{x+y}$.  However, that solution is implicit in $y$, so I couldn't re-use it.

Then I tried making the problem homogeneous in $\frac{y}{x}$, but I ended up with a loose $y$ term.

Now I'm out of ideas.  Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: $u*x=y$ should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=y/x$ or $y=vx$. Then by the product rule $y'=v+v'x$ and by substitution
$$v+v'x = v \frac{1+v}{1-v}$$
$$v'x=\frac{v+v^2}{1-v}-\frac{v-v^2}{1-v}=2\frac{v^2}{1-v}$$
and it remains to integrate.

Comment: You missed the x term: the end should be $v'x=\frac{2v^2}{1-v}$.  However, you helped me find what I was doing wrong, so thanks!

Comment: @KorganRivera, you are right about the x factor but the edit is wrong!

Comment: The edit in my comment above?  It's the same as your correction, so...

Comment: Whoops, it was someone else's incorrect edit, not yours.

Comment: I just noticed, I posted the wrong question.  I knew how to solve this one already -_-